# Popup windows with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After searching for a few hours I could not find the answer I seek, so am submitting a question here.
How would I add on/click popup windows into existing map: http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/vectormaps/vancouver/Vancouver%20Map.html?

An example of the functions and look I am after: http://www.discoverlosangeles.com/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which ones you are referring to... but you should use on click listeners

Check out the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

The whole idea is that you bind a listener to certain events and when they occur, you fire off some other method. So, if you have a div with some data in it, you can have it reposition to the point of the click, take in some input data and appear. Once the click is lifted or leaves an area (also a listener ;) you can hide the div again.